# AWS Lex storage of audio

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot

I’ve created a Lex bot that is integrated with an Amazon Connect work flow. The bot is invoked when the user calls the phone number specified in the Connect instance, and the bot itself invokes a Lambda function for initialisation & validation and fulfilment. The bot asks several questions that require the caller to provide simple responses. It all works OK, so far so good. I would like to add a final question that asks the caller for their comments. This could be any spoken text, including non-English words. I would like to be able to capture this Comment slot value as an audio stream or file, perhaps for storage in S3, with the goal of emailing a call centre administrator and providing the audio file as an MP3 or WAV attachment. Is there any way of doing this in Lex?

I’ve seen mention of ‘User utterance storage’ here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/amazon-connect-with-amazon-lex-press-or-say-input/, but there’s no such setting visible in my Lex console.

I’m aware that Connect can be configured to store a recording in S3, but I need to be able to access the recording for the current phone call from within the Lambda function in order to attach it to an email. Any advice on how to achieve this, or suggestions for a workaround, would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Connect call recording can only record conversations once an agent accepts the call. Currently Connect cannot record voice in the Contact Flows. So in regards to getting the raw audio from Connect, that is not possible.

However, it looks like you can get it from lex if you developed an external application (could be lambda) that gets utterances: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_GetUtterancesView.html

I also do not see the option to enable or disable user utterance storage in Lex, but this makes me think that by default, all are recorded: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_DeleteUtterances.html

Comment: rocketlobster, I think you're right. Hopefully, AWS will incorporate audio-stream-management functionality into Lex in the near future.